# How many number of String objects created in below code?

Tags: java

Am trying to find the number of String objects created in the below code.
I think it is 4 because `String`s are immutable, so each of the first two lines in prod() method will create one object, and the third line will create 2 objects. So total 4 obejcts will be created. Could anybody clarify on that?

```
public class Solution {

    public void prod() {
        String str="Sku";
        str=str+"001";
        String skuId= str.substring(3,6);
        System.out.println(skuId.toString());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Solution().prod();
    }
}
```

Comment: @CodeShark I'm sure is not two :).

Comment: Please edit your question and explain why do you think it's 4 (a magical number without explanation), otherwise this question is off topic.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so each of the first two lines in prod() method will create one object, and the third line will create 2 objects. So total 4 obejcts will be created.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Is it really a duplicate given the answer is different?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Should I ask another question about counting `String` instances where the answers is 7? Anything that answers how to count is a duplicate to these types of questions.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it is interesting that the accepted answer is either incorrect or makes different assumptions..

Comment: @PeterLawrey You should downvote it and post a comment explaining why it's wrong.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis a big difference is that in the previous answer you might assume that the String literals were loaded when the class was loaded (at least for Java 6 and older) but in Java 7 and in the case above, you can't assume the String literals had been loaded already and this changes the answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey ... I don't know what else to tell you. You've been here longer than me. We see this question 5 times a day. There are hundreds of duplicates, ten of which are in the Related section to right of the screen. If you don't think any of them apply, fine, but I think you're wrong and it's useless to keep answering them. I would prefer you add your answer to one of those instead duplicates instead, one with a lot of views.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I take you point about the question not adding a lot of value to the many questions already asked on this topic. Really, it's the wrong question to be asking a virtual machine in the first place.  I have added rant here on the subject. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/common-misconception-how-many-objects.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey The 2500 strings is pretty great.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis on my first attempt I got 5500 which is more than I thought possible.  This was the lowest number I could get.

Answer (score 1):

I think is 4. Below my explanation.

```
public class Solution {
    public void prod() {
        String str = "Sku"; // first
        str = str + "001"; // second when create "001" and third when concat strings
        String skuId = str.substring(3, 6); //fourth
        System.out.println(skuId.toString()); //method toString don't create new string
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Solution().prod();

    }
}
```

1. "Sku" //create new
2. "001" //create new
3. "Sku001" //result of `str + "001"` operations
4. "001" //result of `str.substring(3, 6)`. Substring method return new String()

Comment: While correct, a quibble is that `String.concat` is not actually used here.

Comment: Also, `String.toString()` returns `this` so no String object is created here.

Comment: @Tunaki and OP don't state that, which makes this post right.

Comment: String skuId = str.substring(3, 6);     This lines will create 2 objects

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza true, but the post could have explained that `toString` doesn't create a new object.

Comment: @prabhakarReddyG Two objects in Java 7u6+ one `String` and one `char[]` Before then it would just create one String.

Comment: Correct for number of `String` objects involved, but notice that the `+` operator also allocates a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Andreas from Java 5.0+ correct.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7, the first time the code is run the String literals will be loaded which makes 4, but after that the `prod()` method would only create 2 `String` objects.

Before Java 7, the String literals were loaded when the class was loaded, so the method would only ever add two more Strings.

This of course leaves out the `char[]` in each String which is another object.

BTW, the very first time this class is loaded and run, the JVM actually creates many String objects not visible here.

For example to load the `Solution` class it first looks up the class name using the `"Solution"` String.